# Do we need setTimeout for short polling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, polling

If I want to implement short polling like this:

```
function firstCall(){
   $.ajax({
     ...
     success: function(response){
         if (response.OK == "OK"){
              secondCall();
         }else{
            firstCall();
         }
     }
  });

}
```

Will this be enough? or do I really need to surround the `firstCall()` in else clause with `setTimeout` ?Thanks

Comment: How hard do you want to hit your server?  This could result in 10+ requests per second.  Also, you should handle AJAX errors.

Comment: There are so many good alternatives to this kind of aggressive "are we there yet?" polling. Is this really your only option?

Comment: Oh geesh. Thanks for pointing out. SO obvious. @JamesMcLaughlin Mind to share?

Comment: Comet/long-polling, websockets, ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend you to use a little timeout, because now you are creating a lot of traffic to your server. Ajax is fast and `success` will be executed very often.

So I recommend you to use *setTimeout* or *setInterval* instead!

Comment: Yes, I would use setTimeout or setInterval instead of this solution

Answer (score 4):

This solution relies on the first call to be a success.  If at any point in time your code doesn't "succeed" (perhaps there was a server hiccup?), your "polling" will stop until a page refresh.

You could use `setInterval` to call that method on a defined interval, which avoids this problem:

```
setInterval(function(){
    $.ajax({}); // Your ajax here
}, 1000);
```

With both solutions, your server will be handling a lot of requests it might not need to.  You can use a library like [PollJS](https://github.com/mtrpcic/polljs) (shameless self plug) to add increasing delays, which will increase performance and decrease bandwidth:

```
// Start a poller
Poll.start({
    name: "example_poller",
    interval: 1000,
    increment: 200,
    action: function(){
        $.ajax({}); // Your ajax here
    }
});

// If you want to stop it, just use the name
Poll.stop("example_poller");
```

Answer (score 1):

You need `setTimeout()` if you want to reduce requests to server

Answer (score 1):

you'll need to setTimeout if you don't want to wait to user action or ajax response to trigger an event after a certain time, otherwise you may do wait for the ajax call success or error events.